# Show <select> dropdown in jquery popup

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to show `<select menu>` in a jquery popup but having issues. for some reason it does not show it at all. I've change z-index properties for my `<select>` tag but still no luck. can anyone help?

jQuery popup code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$("#update_work_order_general").fancybox().trigger('click');
    $("#loader .canvas").html($("#update_work_order_general").html()).css("padding", "20px");
    $(".overlay").show();
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").offset().top + 40
    }, 1000);
    $("#loader").fadeIn(500).show();
});
```

Popup works, just that it does not show my `<select menu>`

html code:

```
<div id="update_work_order_general" style="width:950px;display: none;">

<table class="seltable" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" >
<tr>
<td class="form-head" align="left" colspan="10">Information</td>

<tr>
<td align="left">&nbsp;<b>Work Order Type</b></td>
<td>
<select class="selmenu-wo" name="type" >
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">Employee</option>
<option value="2">Special Forces</option>
<option value="3">Test</option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Css :

```
.selmenu-wo { 
font-size: 13px; 
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-top:5px;
padding: 6px;  
border: 1px solid #C9C9C9; 
position:relative;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Does your console show any error?

Comment: Please show html part also.

Comment: Please post your jQuery popup code and your HTML markup

Comment: Make sure your <select> control id is unique in the DOM

Comment: `#update_work_order_general` which element is this? is it your `select`?

Comment: I see a `<div>` then a `<tr>`, where's the `<table>` ?

Comment: it is unique in the form, I am using #update_work_order_general to display the entire div in the popup, if I change it to block, everything works fine, just does not show in the popup

Comment: There are more < select menu > in the form, I did not include them all here, just 1 for the example.

Comment: How are you opening the popup? jQuery UI? Is working here http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dvs8R/

Comment: I am using fancybox lib, jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

remove the `colspan` attribute:

```
<td class="form-head" align="left" colspan="10">Information</td>
    //----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^---remove this attribute
```

Comment: why `colspan=10` is there?

Comment: using that to span the table header across the page for other pages, I can see that it's not necessary here though but regardless if I span it or not, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```
$("select[name='type'], select[name='type2']").attr('style','');
```

after

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#loader .canvas").html($("#update_work_order_general").html()).css("padding","20px");
$(".overlay").show();
$("html, body").animate({
scrollTop: $("body").offset().top+40
},1000);
$("#loader").fadeIn(500).show();
```